# c# ninja script invalid toke '=' in class struct ,member declaratione

Tags: c#

cs1519 error code. I am using  c# in ninjasrcipt I have following error.

```
    [Display(Name = "Buy", GroupName = "01. Profile", Order = 20)]
    public System.Windows.Media.Brush BuyLadderBrush// here it showing class member declaratione expected
    { get; set; } =  Brushes.LightGreen ; //in this line am getting invalid token ';' and '=' eror
    [Browsable(false)]
    public string BuyLadderBrushSerializable
```

2.

```
    protected void DisposeUnmanagedGraphics()
    {
        BuyLadderBrushDx?.Dispose(); BuyLadderBrushDx = null;//all this case expression expected  error 
        SellLadderBrushDx?.Dispose(); SellLadderBrushDx = null;
        PositiveDeltaBrushDx?.Dispose(); PositiveDeltaBrushDx = null;
        NegativeDeltaBrushDx?.Dispose(); NegativeDeltaBrushDx = null;
        ChartBackgroundBrushDx?.Dispose(); ChartBackgroundBrushDx = null;
    }
```

Comment: Which C# and .NET version is your project targeting?

Comment: 4.5 .net am using this on eby the ninjatrader , i need to work on ninjascript.